# Submit Orbeon hidden form field data

Tags: forms, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I use the send-button (formally workflow-send) to submit Orbeon form data as XML to a servlet. My send-configuration looks like this:

```
    <property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
  value='validate-all
         then send(
         uri      = "http://10.120.40.24:8080/formhandler/",
         replace  = "none",
         method   = "post",
         content  = "xml"
         )
         then navigate("success-page")
         recover navigate("error-page")'/>
```

I use hidden fields to pass some parameters to the form, e.g. some ids the user should not see.
Therefore, I use a hidden input field (`visibility = false()`) and `xxf:get-request-parameter('task_id')` to get the parameter from the url.

When I submit the form, the data from the hidden field gets not submitted (it is not included in the generated XML). I think this is a very common use case.

Therefore my question, how can I configure that hidden field data also gets submitted using the send-button?

Thanks and best regards
Ben

Comment: So, you have an input field that get as value (via a calculation binding i guess) an hidden param. I think, if you have the right binding and the right instance element to store the value, this should work. Could you show us a bit of your xforms code ? At least, part of the instance, bindings and view related to this control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with the `prune` property with setting `prune=false`:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
  value='validate-all
         then send(
         uri      = "http://10.120.40.24:8080/formhandler/",
         replace  = "none",
         prune    = "false",
         method   = "post",
         content  = "xml"
         )
         then navigate("success-page")
         recover navigate("error page")'/>
```